# Github Mac Client - no rollback possible - button grayed out

Tags: git

This one is killing me.
I'm not able to perform a rollback to a certain commit. The button is grayed out (see screenshot).
On the Command-Line it's working though.

[image]

Comment: By "rollback", do you mean revert?

Comment: After clicking the icon you **should** be able to either "Revert this commit" or "Roll Back to this commit".
See here: https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-previous-commits/

Comment: <del>Did you publish/push these changes?  I have not used Github For Mac but I wouldn't be surprised if they disallow undoing pushed commits.</del> Nevermind, I just tested it.  Also, from your screenshot your version seems to be out of date.  The latest I have is 194.  Try updating?

Comment: If it's only local or also remote does not change it. I'm also using the latest version (194).

Answer (score 0):

I just received the answer from the github-support:

> This sounds like a known issue with the Accessibility features on OS X
>   Yosemite.
>
> We're currently working on a fix, but, in the meantime, you may be
>   able to work around the problem by going to System Preferences >
>   Security & Privacy pane > Privacy tab > Accessibility, then
>   quitting/unchecking any apps listed there.